# CSS3 Transition Safari issue all prefixes added

Tags: css, safari, css-animations

I have simple **css animation** and it works perfectly in all browsers except safari, I tried all solutions from stackoverflow but I'm out of ideas, anyone see something that can couse the problem here ?

```
.marquee {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-animation: marquee linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: marquee linear infinite;
  animation-duration: 35s;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-top: 150px;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% { -webkit-transform: translate(0,0); -moz-transform: translate(0,0); -o-transform: translate(0,0);}
  100% { -webkit-transform: translate(0,-100%); -moz-transform: translate(0,-100%); -o-transform: translate(0,-100%); }
}
```

Comment: what version of safari are you testing on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your CSS code :

- you need to specify the animation shorthand without the vendor prefix (*note that it needs to be declared after the pefixed ones*)
- you are missing the prefixes on the `animation-duration` declaration
- you need to add the `@keyframe` [at-rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/At-rule) with the vendor prefixes and the according prefixes on the properties that need them (in your case `transform`).

```css
.marquee {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-animation: marquee linear infinite;
     -moz-animation: marquee linear infinite;
          animation: marquee linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 35s;
     -moz-animation-duration: 35s;
          animation-duration: 35s;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-top: 150px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
  0%   { -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: translate(0, -100%); }
}
@-moz-keyframes marquee {
  0%   { -moz-transform: translate(0, 0); }
  100% { -moz-transform: translate(0, -100%); }
}
@keyframes marquee {
  0%   { transform: translate(0, 0); }
  100% { transform: translate(0, -100%); }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">test</div>
```

More info :

- CSS tricks article : [Keyframe Animation Syntax](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/)
- [animation support table on canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=css-animation)
- [2d transfoms support table on canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)